# Assigning apply-template output(which is a attachment) to a variable in XSLT

Tags: xslt

i have a template which reads the attachment.

i am using apply-templates to do that.after which i want to save the output of this to a variable for further processing.is it possible to store a file to a variable in xslt.or is there any feasibility to do the same with some other option.

Can someone help me...

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:variable name="foo">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:variable>
```

will capture the apply-templates' output into  a Result Tree Fragment (XSLT 1.0) or Temporary Tree (XSLT 2.0) and assign that to the variable.

in XSLT 1.0, if you want to further process the contents of the RTF rather than just writing it to the output later on, you'll need to do something slightly nonstandard and use an extension function (provided by most XSLT processors) to convert it to a nodeset. XSLT 2.0's introduction of the Temporary Tree concept removed the distinction between the two.