# xslt 1.0 applying a template to literally specified nodes stored in a variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, metaprogramming

I am trying to create a little DSL in XSLT. The most basic example would be xslt code like:

```xml
<xsl:text>hi: </xsl:text><myelm />
```

my goal is to get his to expand to `hi: MYELM`. So far, I have tried

```xml
<xsl:template match="myelm">MYELM</xsl:template>
<xsl:variable name="tmp">
   <xsl:text>hi: </xsl:text><myelm />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:apply-templates select="$tmp" />
```

however, `apply-templates` complains about `$tmp` not storing a nodes list. An answer [Assigning apply-template output(which is a attachment) to a variable in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779461/assigning-apply-template-outputwhich-is-a-attachment-to-a-variable-in-xslt) suggests that `$tmp` is a fragment rather than a nodes list and that in XSLT 1.0 it is difficult to convert a fragment to a nodes list.

My question is: is there a way to convert `$tmp` to a node list, or is there another way to accomplish my goal of typing `<myelm />` in my XSLT source file and having it expand via the specified template? (Running xsltproc on the XSL file itself to preprocess it is not an option...)

Comment: You can convert a result tree fragment to a node-set using `exsl:node-set($tmp)` (with `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"`) being declared. Be aware that you have a document node/root node (matched by `/`) then so any direct `<xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($tmp)"/>` will be looking for a a template matching `/`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I don't understand your comment about templates matching `/` (I am new to XSLT...). Can you explain more?

Comment: A result tree fragment (which you have in your variable) with be converted to a document node, any use of the shown apply-templates will push that document node to a matching template so what happens then depends on your existing templates, if you already have one with `match="/"` it will be used (which is often not what you want in that case); perhaps doing e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($tmp)/node()"/>` is more what you want (as it processes the child nodes in that document (e.g. the text node and the element).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve],  not snippets of code taken out of context. Also state which XSLT 1.0 processor you're using.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Martin Honnen I was able to make it work:

After adding `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"` to the stylesheet, I can then do

```xml
<xsl:template match="myelm">MYELM</xsl:template>
<xsl:variable name="tmp">
   <xsl:text>hi: </xsl:text><myelm />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($tmp)/*" />
```

The `/*` after `node-set()` is required to get the templates to apply.

Comment: This is not helping anyone. We don't know what you are trying to accomplish here, and for what purpose (DSL??? Digital Subscriber Line???) . There is very likely a much better way to do it. It makes no sense to apply templates - i.e. to **transform** - an XML fragment that is created entirely in the XSLT stylesheet. You could simply create it in its final form and copy it to the output where required (or even simpler, write it directly to the output).

Comment: @michael.hor257k In this case, DSL stands for Domain Specific Language. I am creating a JSON output for xslt 1.0. In this case, I'd like to write XML in the xslt file but have the final output be JSON, like you can do in xslt 3.0.